# finding initial vertical velocity and final vertical velocity - projectile motion

Tags: projectile-motion

find initial vertical velocity and final vertical velocity when a ball has a mass of 280g, flight time of 0.69s and has a length of 0.76m. height of strike is 0.8m.

this is a projectile motion question.
i'm a little bit stuck since it doesn't give angle
- thanks

Comment: Do my homework ?

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given is the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

From the following

- $ x = v_0 t \cos(\theta)$
- $y = v_0 t \sin(\theta) - \frac{1}{2}gt^2$

set

- $y_{max} = v_0 (\bar t/2) \sin(\theta) - \frac{1}{2}g(\bar t/2)^2$
- $ x_{max} = v_0 \bar t \cos(\theta)$

from which find $\theta$ and $v_0$.